# Load page in div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This jQuery code loads a specific page within a div (this works):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#button2").on("click", function(){  
                $("#loader").load($("#button2").attr("page"));
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Also, I have 2 links with an attribute "page" indicating the html file to be loaded in the div:

```
<li><a href="#" title="" id="button2" page="page1.html">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" id="button2" page="page2.html">Link 2</a></li>
```

This is the div where the page is loaded:

```
<div id="loader"></div>
```

The problem is that only loads "page1.html" when I click on the first link. If I click on the second link does not load "page2.html".

I think it may be a problem of the id attribute of link "button2" on repeat maybe something happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: FIrst thing, IDs should be unique. use `data-page` as attribute

Comment: Use .text() or .html() instead of load(). Load is to do ajax calls.

Comment: Store the page in an attribute called `data-page`

Comment: @DhavalMarthak No, not only the first thing, but basically the answer... @wumm But clearly he wants to load the contents of a web page. Btw @OP, please use `data-page` instead of `page` attribute.

Comment: @adam Why? It is already in the link. You could as well use `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the link, if JS is enabled.

Comment: Keep in mind, you can only load a page that is on your website, not a page from a external server.

Comment: @feeela Because HTML5 specifically reserves `data-` prefixed attributes to store custom additional information along with elements within your DOM. Completely custom attributes are, from a strict view, prohibited. @user0000001 Keep in mind that AJAX is subject to CORS which, when used correctly, **does** allow you to access resources not on the same domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not use same ids for elements. Each id attribute must be unique (according to [HTML4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) specs).

It would be better to use a class to identify these buttons instead, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".buttons").on("click", function(){  
            $("#loader").load($(this).attr("page"));
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the button's HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" title="" class="buttons" page="page1.html">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" class="buttons" page="page2.html">Link 2</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

"What am I doing wrong?"

You are using duplicate ID's, which is forbidden in HTML. Use a class name or an element selector instead. You can refer to the currently clicked button inside the event handler by `$(this)`:

```
<li><a href="#" title="" class="button" page="page1.html">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="" class="button" page="page2.html">Link 2</a></li>

$(".button2").on("click", function(){  
    $("#loader").load($(this).attr("page"));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

button2 Class is not there. Replace with button

Comment: You should review your answer for readability and clarity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).